# Why does the 'same' code looks different in the same browser with the same size, where one deployment is on localhost and the other remote

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fonts, material-ui

I have some Material-UI Table where I styled the headers and tables.

When I was running the app locally with `yarn start` I have this look:

[image: Looks with yarn start on localhost:3000]

And this is how it looks like on the remote system:

[image: Looks after yarn build on a remote server]

It's not like the font-size is different, but also it's not centred.
I am not really sure what's the reason for it to look different on the same browser, on the same system just in a different tab.

Here are the relevant code changes I did apply:

```
const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme }) => ({
  '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
  },
  // hide last border
  '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': {
    border: 0,
  },
}));

const StyledAvatar = styled(Avatar)`
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #777;
`;

const NoTableCellPadding = styled(TableCell)`
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-family: Roboto;
  text-align: center;

  &.MuiTableCell-head {
    background: linear-gradient(#ddd, #fff 40%, #ddd);
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
 
  &.MuiTableCell-head:last-child th' {
    border-right: none;
  }
`;
```

So now I am wondering what could be the reasons, where to look for that the changes don't seem to be applied. Any hints?

Comment: well what does console say, is it showing the same elements using same css? if they are different then you havent deployed correctly i imagine

Comment: The console doesn't show anything, not even any warnings. The elements are also the same, as it is react the only problem could be some issue with webpack

Answer (score 0):

In the end it turned out to be this:

```
const NoTableCellPadding = styled(TableCell)`
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-family: Roboto;
  text-align: center;
...
```

It needs to be like this:

```
const NoTableCellPadding = styled(TableCell)`
  & {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    font-family: Roboto;
    text-align: center;
  }
...
```

Which doesn't explain however why I didn't see this locally, but it's quite possible that this is related to the way how the hot reload feature of the `yarn start` works and how it adds the style information. Using styled results in optimized CSS after it has been compiled for a release build.

Henty gave a good comment however, to check for the differences. It was however not quite obvious why they were different until I saw masses of `<style>` tags in the inspector.

So thanks Henty!